# How should be Folder Structure in Coded UI?

Tags: qtp, coded-ui-tests

I want to create specific folders structure for my Coded Ui tests.

How should it be?

As like QTP Framework. Can we keep specific files to specific folders, if yes then can anybody share format.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it depends on the Framework and Project which you working.

yes, we can keep specific files in specific folders. For any project generally there will be few common folder like:

1. parent Folder : Usually a ProjectName

1.1 Test.
1.1.1 - DataSheet.
1.1.2 - Functions.
1.1.2.1  - ApplicationFunctions.
1.1.2.2 - FrameworkFunctions.
1.1.3 - Configurations
1.1.4- Recovery Scenarios.
1.1.5-Results
1.1.6-Driver
1.1.7-Repository

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for the TailSpinUITestProject by Microsoft. They put all coded ui files within a sub folder called "UI".

http://cid-2779e0ac1e14a80b.office.live.com/browse.aspx/Public